# when i set popup outside touchable to false edit text does not showing keyboard in pop up window

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I have a PopupWindow on my activity, the popupWindow has Edit text. The thing is when i set popup Window outside touchable to false Edit text does not opening keyboard in pop up window in android and i am dismissing the popup by giving cancel button inside popup. Please help thanks in advance.

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.repeat, null);
            int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            boolean focusable = false; 
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);

            // show the popup window
            // which view you pass in doesn't matter, it is only used for the window tolken
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            final LinearLayout until = popupView.findViewById(R.id.Until);
            Button pop_done = popupView.findViewById(R.id.pop_done);
            Button pop_cancel = popupView.findViewById(R.id.pop_cancel);
            dropdown = popupView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            final EditText repetition = popupView.findViewById(R.id.repeat_times);
```

Comment: You need to add InputMethodManager when click on ediitext

Comment: not working tried..

Comment: I update my answer please check.

Answer (score 0):

- Try this

  ```
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                  getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          final View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.repeat, null);
          int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
          int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
          final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height);
          popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
          popupWindow.update();
          // show the popup window
          // which view you pass in doesn't matter, it is only used for the window tolken
          popupWindow.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
          popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);
          final LinearLayout until = popupView.findViewById(R.id.Until);
          Button pop_done = popupView.findViewById(R.id.pop_done);
          Button pop_cancel = popupView.findViewById(R.id.pop_cancel);
          Spinner dropdown = popupView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
          final EditText repetition = popupView.findViewById(R.id.repeat_times);
  ```

Comment: edit text is working but i want to avoid popup dismiss when we touch outside...

Comment: i i set focusable to false...i can avoid dismiss popup...but edittext won't show keyboard...

Comment: Why you want to do focusable false?

Comment: Its a different thing touchable and focusable.

Comment: hey thanks for the solution...but i tried by taking the layout with match parent and kept a transparent background...inside that layout i took the popup window with center gravity...in that case entire match parent is pop up...

Comment: Yes but there is different thing outsidetouchable and focusable

Comment: When you setFocusable it means you set automatically set inputmethod and touchable means you touch outside popup it will destrou popup if you set true

Comment: Check my answer you dont need to do match parent layout